# Circle Collider Slides on Box Collider when Velocity is slowing down?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a carrom 2D game for learning, i added box colliders 2D all sides and for striker circle collider 2D, and set physics material for all as friction 0 and bounciness 1. and Linear Drag to 1 for stiker.

It all works fine when velocity of impact of striker with sides but velocity is slow its dragging on slides instead of bouncing. where am i doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the problem is but seems like something to do with how the engine is resolving the physics. Try resolving the collision for the individual carrom tokens manually when they hit a surface instead of relying on physics material.

Here is a simple 2D example:

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]
public class ReflectingObject : MonoBehaviour {
    
    [Range(0f, 1f)]
    public float bounciness = 1;

    private Rigidbody2D m_Rb;

    void Awake() {
        m_Rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col) {
        if(col.contactCount > 0) {
           
            // Get the collision contact point
            ContactPoint2D point = col.contacts[0];
            
            // Get the current speed of this object
            float speed = m_Rb.velocity.magnitude;

            // Get the direction where this object is heading to
            Vector2 oldDirection = (Vector2)m_Rb.velocity.normalized;
            
            // Get the reflected direction
            Vector2 newDirection = Vector2.Reflect(oldDirection, point.normal).normalized;
            
            // Calculate new velocity based on bounciness
            Vector2 newVelocity = newDirection * speed * bounciness;
            
            // Assign the velocity
            m_Rb.velocity = newVelocity;
        }
    }
}
```

Something like this.
Assign this Component to the objects which you want to reflect on collision.